# How to find the value of $K_c$?

Tags: equilibrium

This is part of my homework. Given the chemical equation :
$$\ce{Sb2S3_{(s)} + 3H2_{(g)} <=>2Sb_{(s)} + 3H2S_{(g)}}\text{        }K_{p}=0,429\text{ at }713\text{K}$$
What is the value of $K_c$ for the reaction?

I used the formula : $K_p = K_c(RT)^{\Delta n}$, but I know that $\Delta n$  considers only the coefficients of the reactants and the products of gas forms, so $\Delta n = 3-3=0 \Rightarrow K_c=K_p$?

Am I right? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks correct to me. Note, however, that such questions regarding proof-reading are rarely off-topic on Chemistry.SE: [Policy on AMIRITE questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/policy-on-amirite-questions).

Comment: Ups...I am sorry, this is my first post actually... thanks for the notice anyway.